# Append a php file with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, append

i have a file which echoes out data from a database.

I wish to have a load more button which appends this file so that it will keep loading the rest of the results.

The php page works fine but need help with the jquery...

have used this else where for a json return but dont think this is needed for this.

So i am trying this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#loadmore").click(function () {
     $("#content").append('includes/loadmorebuilds.php');
});
});
```

In essence, this works but it appends 'includes/loadmorebuilds.php' as just that. I simply appends those words and not the file.

Any help on this?

Many thanks!

Comment: You're now appending `#content` with the _string_ `'includes/loadmorebuilds.php'`. If you want to fetch the file itself I'd suggest you use `.load()` to fetch the file asynchronously

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `$.ajax` to get content from file to be appended into DOM. One important thing is that **you should use Relative PATH to your web root** on url parameter in `$.ajax`

So it will become like this

```
$('#loadmore').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
       url: '/relative/path/to/your/script',
       success: function(html) {
          $("#content").append(html);
       }
    });
});
```

And make sure you should be able to access your script on http://www.example.com/relative/path/to/your/script

Comment: This amongst others works. However it only works if i change my loaded file to something simple e.g. a php echo with a word.

Its not working my query etc on it... anything i need to change?

Comment: try using `var_dump();` on query result then `exit;` and see what you got. Your query might be returning NULL values or there's an error on your code. You could access the script directly via URL or AJAX calls.

Comment: the thing is, if i try do a simple php include of the file then everything loads fine... :/

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

```
$('#content').load('includes/loadmorebuilds.php');
```

Which will replace the content of `#content` with the new html.

Or this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'includes/loadmorebuilds.php'
}).done(function(data) {
    $('#content').append(data);
});
```

Which will append the new data.

Answer (score 2):

use **$.ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".loader").click(function(){

      $.ajax({
                url:"index.php",
                dataType:"html",
                type:'POST', 

                beforeSend: function(){
                },
                success:function(result){
                      $(".content").append(result);
                 },

        });
    });
    });
```